# Remove Applied trainsition properties

Tags: jquery, html, css

How to Remove all applied Transition property from an image  using j query . i have applied some effect onClick() of image .  on next click i can still see those properties in Firebug how to Remove them completely.

i have tried this ,

```
    $(obj).css("-webkit-transition","all 1.0s linear");
    $(obj).css("transition","all 1.0s linear");
    $(obj).css("-webkit-transform","");
```

an this,

```
 $(obj).addClass('notransition');

  .notransition {
  -webkit-transition: none !important;
  -moz-transition: none !important;
  -o-transition: none !important;
  -ms-transition: none !important;
  transition: none !important;
}
```

Comment: maybe try `$(obj).removeClass('transitionclass');` or if you need a toggle, `$(obj).toggleClass('transitionclass notransition');`

Comment: Use class-names, rather than adding properties to the `style` attribute.

Comment: Use `$(obj).css("-webkit-transition","");` for all transitions

Comment: @DavidThomas  do you mean 2 code which i have tried above?

Comment: @VijayPatel i tried $(obj).css("-webkit-transition",""); this but still i can see the transition in firebug.

Comment: Possibly, yes: but without seeing how you're animating/transitioning the elements in the first place we can't answer except with suggestions.

Comment: Have you tried for all? 
`$(obj).css("-webkit-transition","");
    $(obj).css("transition","");
    $(obj).css("-webkit-transform","");`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the ['initial' value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/initial_value)?

Comment: Sorry i am new to this community. I posted this as an answer, because i wasn't able to comment.
So to my understanding - Answers are only accepted if they provide a (tested) solution?

Comment: No problem. Answer doesnt have to be 'tested' to be valid - but it should (usually) be more detailed than yours. Commenting is totally appropriate here - but rules are rules.